# sort tracemalloc statistics by size

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-leaks, tracemalloc

I have this code:

```
def print_statistics(s: Snapshot, s2: Snapshot):
    stats = s2.compare_to(s, 'lineno')
    for stat in stats[:20]:
        print(stat)

def some_func()
    tracemalloc.start(50)
    s = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
    .
    .
    Code
    .
    .
    s2 = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
    print_statistics(s, s2)
```

and this is a sample of the print:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py:353: size=2672 B (+2672 B), count=33 (+33), average=81 B
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prometheus_client/values.py:15: size=1664 B (+1664 B), count=32 (+32), average=52 B
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prometheus_client/metrics.py:521: size=1304 B (+1304 B), count=17 (+17), average=77 B
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prometheus_client/values.py:16: size=1152 B (+1152 B), count=32 (+32), average=36 B
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/tracemalloc.py:185: size=13.2 KiB (+5328 B), count=281 (+111), average=48 B
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py:353: size=5344 B (-2672 B), count=66 (-33), average=81 B
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/tracemalloc.py:102: size=5891 B (+2366 B), count=37 (+16), average=159 B
```

Am I missing something with how I read it?
It seems that the order is pretty random.

What do I need to do to actually see the part of code that use the most memory?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html) has an example showing how to [display the top 10](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html#examples).

Comment: @martineau if you look at my function `print_statistics` you can see I do the same thing

Comment: Beneath the example of the output of the top 10, the documentation explains what the lines mean — and also says to "See [Snapshot.statistics()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html#tracemalloc.Snapshot.statistics) for more options."

Comment: @martineau What exactly do you see there that explains that order?

Comment: If you look at the `size=` values shown, you'll note that they're in descending order. Admittedly the documentation doesn't explicitly point those details out — but I personally think it's fairly obvious.

Comment: @martineau You think 1152 B > 13.2 KiB > 5344 B > 5891 B?

Comment: @KellyBundy: All I know is that the ones shown in the documentation are in strictly descending order (as you would expect a "top 10" list to be in). The OP is **not** doing exactly what's in the documentation (despite what they claim).

Comment: @martineau What are they doing differently? And the doc's output contains size 298 KiB followed by size 1005 KiB.

Comment: @EmaIl The output looks correct to me, looks like you just need to realize what you're doing and read the documentation of the function you're using.

Comment: @martineau That's just **you** looking/linking at the wrong example of the documentation. Look at the [immediately following example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html#compute-differences), the one showing the "Top 10 **differences**".

Comment: @KellyBundy: It's **me** referring to the second documentation link in **my** original comment (that the OP responded to by saying they were doing the same thing). In the example to which **you** refer, the values for `size=` in the parentheses — such as `size=8173 KiB (+4428 KiB)` — are what is in descending order. I believe these are the differences between the two sets of statistics being compared (esp since they are signed values). Anyway, give it a rest because I'm through responding to you.

Comment: Yeah I did look past it, since I saw that beneath it was the part I looked for. I also did manage to make it in a descending order, when I added `cumulative=True` to the `compare_to` function. Still not 100% percent sure why it made the difference, but it worked...

Comment: @EmaIl I don't understand what `cumulative` does, but what I meant when I said you need to realize what you're doing is that you're apparently showing *two* snapshot differences, not just one. Because `json/decoder.py:353` appears twice and because of that one increase from 1152 B to 5328 B (all other changes are decreasing).